# Moq WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers

Tags: moq

I am pretty new at Moq.  I am creating a unit test project using Moq.
Can someone please help me understand how to Moq this line of code?

```
    class Serviceclass : IService
    {

        //properties and methods here
        //I am Moqing this and this is my first line of code in my method
        public Response RequestMethod(string id, RequestData request)
        {
            WebHeaderCollection headers = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers;

            //Some more code here
        }
        .....
  }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You are going to have to provide more context that one line of code. Plus that line looks like it is calling a static member. Which are difficult to mock.

Comment: I added some more code. Yes it is a static member call ...

Comment: Wrap the static call in an abstraction you control and inject that into the service. This allow for more flexibility if mock is needed for unit testing in isolation.

Comment: Thank you, Is there any good example that you can point me to that I can follow?

Comment: the official website is a good start: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart